# Creating an alias for a class

Tags: java, class

I am trying to figure out how to alias a class

```
public class Mappy {

  public static Class<Asyncc> Map = Mappy.class;

}
```

importing the above might look like:

```
import org.foo.Mappy.Map;
```

but since Map is a common name, then maybe the user can use the longer name Mappy.

```
import org.foo.Mappy;
```

Is this an acceptable way to alias class?

Comment: this doesn't seem to work at all lol

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "alias a class".

Comment: Ever had a name clash when two different imports have the same class name?

Comment: why don't you use a meaningful name?

Comment: Yeah. You import one and use the fully qualified name of the other. Depending on which you use more frequently. Importing is just a matter of convenience. And with IDEs these days auto-completing everything, you don't even have to type the whole thing anymore.

Answer (score 1):

> Without the use of an appropriate import declaration, the only way to refer to a type declared in another package, or a static member of another type, is to use a fully qualified name (§6.7).
>
> <sup>https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5</sup>

There is no way to alias a class or to refer to it by using a name different from the fully qualified name.

> Ever had a name clash when two different imports have the same class name?

It happens not that often. @RealSkeptic's comment is a good one.

But I wouldn't use import at all to tell that there are at least two same identifiers expressed differently by providing their full names in the file. It would be annoying to check which static import is used.